# Count the number of ListArrays when anyone of the individual ListArrays has duplicate elements

Tags: java, arraylist, methods, return

I need a method that checks many different ArrayLists. For each individual ListArray I need to check for duplicity(any instance of two elements the same) and when the condition is met (ie two elements are the same in an ArrayList) I need to count the amount of times the condition is met and the int value returned after all the ListArrays have been checked. Here is my code so far to give a better idea. It's not complete. I just need guidance with the return type int and how to increase the count when there is duplicity of elements in an individual ListArray

```
private static int findDuplicates(List<Integer> list) {

 int total=0;

 for (int j=0;j<list.size();j++)
   for (int k=j+1;k<list.size();k++)
     if (k!=j && list.get(k).equals(list.get(j)));
 total=+ total;

return total;
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` != `ListArray`

Comment: You have 2 errors. 1) Change `total=+ total;` to `total++;`, to just increment the value by `1`. Or maybe `total += 1;`. 2) Remove `;` at end of `if` statement. --- You should also indent the `total++;` below the `if` statement, to better show the program structure. You should also remove `k!=j`, since your loop logic ensures that `k` is always `> j`.

Comment: Note that `total=+ total` ⇔ `total = +total` ⇔ `total = total` ⇔ a statement that does **nothing**.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a problem with the algorithm too. If an element appears three times in the list, it will count it twice. If it appears four times, it will be counted thrice.

Answer (score 0):

### Syntax and logical problems

1) the `;` at the end of the `if` condition basically prevents the if statement to do anything at all, in other words it's equivalent to an `if` statement with empty body.

2) You're incorrectly incrementing the `total` variable.

3) ensure you include the `{` `}`  braces.

4) you're using the wrong logic to increment `total=+ total;`, it should be `total += total;`

you need to increment by `1`;

```
total += 1;
//or if you prefer
total++;
```

not by `0`:

```
total += total;
```

**Example:**

```
private static int findDuplicates(List<Integer> list) {

 int total=0;

 for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
     for (int k = j + 1; k < list.size(); k++){
        if (k != j && list.get(k).equals(list.get(j))){
            total++;
        }
     }
 }

 return total;
}
```

### Problem within your algorithm

Also, your algorithm appears to have a problem because let's say if an element appears few/several times in the list, it will count it more than once. if that's what you intended then no problem. However, if that's not the case then you can try the approach below.

The approach below basically ignores all the duplicates that have been processed already when encountered later on within the list and proceeds.

```
private static int findDuplicates(List<Integer> list) {

    int total=0;
    List<Integer> tempList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
        for (int k = j + 1; k < list.size(); k++){
             if (k != j && list.get(k).equals(list.get(j)) && !tempList.contains(list.get(k))){
                 tempList.add(list.get(k));
                 total++;
             }
        }
    }

    return total;
}
```

### Expanding on the alternative approach.

let's assume this is the list which we want to pass to the `findDuplicates` method.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(
        1,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,5,6,7,13,13,13,15,16
);

System.out.println(findDuplicates(list));
```

with the approach I have provided it will print `5`, However, with your approach, it will print `16`.

Comment: `total=+1` does *not* increment the value by one.

Comment: @user2387962 if the solution has solved your problem, don't forget to mark answer as accepted. :).